# timetable in a jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to create a timetable in a jTable. For the top row it will display from monday to sunday and the left colume will display the time of the day with 2h interval e.g 1st colume (0000 - 0200), 2nd colume (0200 - 0400) ....

And if i click a button the timing will change from 2h interval to 1h interval. I do not want to hardcode it because i need to do for 2h, 1h, 30min , 15min, 1min, 30sec and 1 sec interval and it will take too long for me to hardcode. Can anyone show me an example or help me create an example for the 2h to 1h interval so that i know what to do?

The data array is for me to store data and are there any other easier or shortcuts for me to store them because if it is in 1 sec interval i got thousands of array i need to type it out.

```
    private void oneHour() //1 interval functions
    {
        if(!once)
        {
            initialize();
            once = true;
        }
        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {"0000 - 0100", data[0][0], data[0][1], data[0][2], data[0][3], data[0][4], data[0][5], data[0][6]},
        {"0100 - 0200", data[2][0], data[2][1], data[2][2], data[2][3], data[2][4], data[2][5], data[2][6]},
        {"0200 - 0300", data[4][0], data[4][1], data[4][2], data[4][3], data[4][4], data[4][5], data[4][6]},
        {"0300 - 0400", data[6][0], data[6][1], data[6][2], data[6][3], data[6][4], data[6][5], data[6][6]},
        {"0400 - 0600", data[8][0], data[8][1], data[8][2], data[8][3], data[8][4], data[8][5], data[8][6]},
        {"0600 - 0700", data[10][0], data[4][1], data[10][2], data[10][3], data[10][4], data[10][5], data[10][6]},
        {"0700 - 0800", data[12][0], data[12][1], data[12][2], data[12][3], data[12][4], data[12][5], data[12][6]},
        {"0800 - 0900", data[14][0], data[14][1], data[14][2], data[14][3], data[14][4], data[14][5], data[14][6]},
        {"0900 - 1000", data[16][0], data[16][1], data[16][2], data[16][3], data[16][4], data[16][5], data[16][6]},
        {"1000 - 1100", data[18][0], data[18][1], data[18][2], data[18][3], data[18][4], data[18][5], data[18][6]},
        {"1100 - 1200", data[20][0], data[20][1], data[20][2], data[20][3], data[20][4], data[20][5], data[20][6]},
        {"1200 - 1300", data[22][0], data[22][1], data[22][2], data[22][3], data[22][4], data[22][5], data[22][6]},
        {"1300 - 1400", data[24][0], data[24][1], data[24][2], data[24][3], data[24][4], data[24][5], data[24][6]},
        {"1400 - 1500", data[26][0], data[26][1], data[26][2], data[26][3], data[26][4], data[26][5], data[26][6]},
        {"1500 - 1600", data[28][0], data[28][1], data[28][2], data[28][3], data[28][4], data[28][5], data[28][6]},
        {"1600 - 1700", data[30][0], data[30][1], data[30][2], data[30][3], data[30][4], data[30][5], data[30][6]},
        {"1700 - 1800", data[32][0], data[32][1], data[32][2], data[32][3], data[32][4], data[32][5], data[32][6]},
        {"1800 - 1900", data[34][0], data[34][1], data[34][2], data[34][3], data[34][4], data[34][5], data[34][6]},
        {"1900 - 2000", data[36][0], data[36][1], data[36][2], data[36][3], data[36][4], data[36][5], data[36][6]},
        {"2000 - 2100", data[38][0], data[38][1], data[38][2], data[38][3], data[38][4], data[38][5], data[38][6]},
        {"2100 - 2200", data[40][0], data[40][1], data[40][2], data[40][3], data[40][4], data[40][5], data[40][6]},
        {"2200 - 2300", data[42][0], data[42][1], data[42][2], data[42][3], data[42][4], data[42][5], data[42][6]},
        {"2300 - 2400", data[44][0], data[44][1], data[44][2], data[44][3], data[44][4], data[44][5], data[44][6]},
        {"2400 - 0000", data[46][0], data[46][1], data[46][2], data[46][3], data[46][4], data[46][5], data[46][6]},

   },
    new String [] {
        "Time/Day", "(Mon)", "(Tue)", "(Wed)", "(Thurs)", "(Fri)", "(Sat)", "(Sun)"
    }
));
    }


    private void twoHour() //2 hour interval functions
    {
        if(!once)
        {
            initialize();
            once = true;
        }
        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {"0000 - 0200", data[0][0], data[0][1], data[0][2], data[0][3], data[0][4], data[0][5], data[0][6]},
        {"0200 - 0400", data[4][0], data[4][1], data[4][2], data[4][3], data[4][4], data[4][5], data[4][6]},
        {"0400 - 0600", data[8][0], data[8][1], data[8][2], data[8][3], data[8][4], data[8][5], data[8][6]},
        {"0600 - 0800", data[12][0], data[12][1], data[12][2], data[12][3], data[12][4], data[12][5], data[12][6]},
        {"0800 - 1000", data[16][0], data[16][1], data[16][2], data[16][3], data[16][4], data[16][5], data[16][6]},
        {"1000 - 1200", data[20][0], data[20][1], data[20][2], data[20][3], data[20][4], data[20][5], data[20][6]},
        {"1200 - 1400", data[24][0], data[24][1], data[24][2], data[24][3], data[24][4], data[24][5], data[24][6]},
        {"1400 - 1600", data[28][0], data[28][1], data[28][2], data[28][3], data[28][4], data[28][5], data[28][6]},
        {"1600 - 1800", data[32][0], data[32][1], data[32][2], data[32][3], data[32][4], data[32][5], data[32][6]},
        {"1800 - 2000", data[36][0], data[36][1], data[36][2], data[36][3], data[36][4], data[36][5], data[36][6]},
        {"2000 - 2200", data[40][0], data[40][1], data[40][2], data[40][3], data[40][4], data[40][5], data[40][6]},
        {"2200 - 2400",data[44][0], data[44][1], data[44][2], data[44][3], data[44][4], data[44][5], data[44][6]}


    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Java Tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). This will help you create your table. Once you have something working you can then ask for more specific help if you get stuck.

Comment: i already did try alot of tutorials on the jtable but non of it helps...

Comment: then please show us the code you have written so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: i hardcode the interval of the time because i do not how to use a loop to print out the timing of the interval. And also for the data arrays which i want to store data.

Comment: What is stored in the data array? How do you know what data elements to use for a specific interval?

Comment: cause i need to store the data in different timing so i created an array to store the data. For example if 0000 - 0200 got a data stored, when you go into 1h interval, 0000 - 0100 and 0100 - 0200 will have the data store in 0000 -0200.